# Ubuntu 12.04 boots very slow

Tags: 12.04, boot, hardware, samsung

I've been using ubuntu since version 10.04 and so far I was never in a situation I could not solve on my own googling other people's questions. In this case, there seem to be such a variety of reasons for ubuntu starting slow that it's hard for me to find the solution.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a Samsung RC530 laptop

The problem is the following: it takes several minutes for ubuntu to start(first until the login appears and then until it loads, being the first one the slowest)

I've checked a couple of questions including http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2137435.html
but I'm still not sure if I have the same problem(that's what I'm trying to figure out!)

in order to speed up the answers here goes the output of dmesg:

```
[    2.179793] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf5000000-0xf60fffff]
[    2.179797] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xf1ffffff 64bit pref]
[    2.179802] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-02]
[    2.179806] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    2.179812] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf7200000-0xf7bfffff]
[    2.179817] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf2c00000-0xf35fffff 64bit pref]
[    2.179825] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PCI bridge to [bus 03-03]
[    2.179829] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
[    2.179835] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xf6800000-0xf71fffff]
[    2.179841] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xf2100000-0xf2afffff 64bit pref]
[    2.179858] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    2.179862] pci 0000:00:01.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.179870] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    2.179875] pci 0000:00:1c.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.179886] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PCI INT D -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    2.179891] pci 0000:00:1c.3: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.179896] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    2.179899] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    2.179901] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    2.179904] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
[    2.179906] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
[    2.179908] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 9 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
[    2.179911] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 10 [mem 0x000dc000-0x000dffff]
[    2.179913] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 11 [mem 0x000e0000-0x000e3fff]
[    2.179916] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 12 [mem 0x000e4000-0x000e7fff]
[    2.179918] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 13 [mem 0xcfa00000-0xfeafffff]
[    2.179920] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 0 [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    2.179923] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0xf5000000-0xf60fffff]
[    2.179925] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 2 [mem 0xe0000000-0xf1ffffff 64bit pref]
[    2.179928] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 0 [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    2.179930] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xf7200000-0xf7bfffff]
[    2.179933] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xf2c00000-0xf35fffff 64bit pref]
[    2.179935] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 0 [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
[    2.179938] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xf6800000-0xf71fffff]
[    2.179940] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0xf2100000-0xf2afffff 64bit pref]
[    2.179969] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    2.180023] IP route cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    2.180170] TCP established hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[    2.180418] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    2.180530] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 131072 bind 65536)
[    2.180532] TCP reno registered
[    2.180535] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    2.180540] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    2.180598] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    2.180611] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
[    2.180623] pci 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    2.180649] pci 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A disabled
[    2.180671] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
[    2.180689] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A disabled
[    2.180741] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    2.181446] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    2.181454] type=2000 audit(1379439860.948:1): initialized
[    2.205653] highmem bounce pool size: 64 pages
[    2.205658] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    2.207801] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    2.207857] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    2.208374] fuse init (API version 7.17)
[    2.208465] msgmni has been set to 1641
[    2.208819] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    2.208846] io scheduler noop registered
[    2.208848] io scheduler deadline registered
[    2.208854] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    2.208937] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.208965] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.209127] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    2.209148] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    2.209223] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x21120
[    2.209225] intel_idle: v0.4 model 0x2A
[    2.209226] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[    2.209302] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    2.209345] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP1] (off-line)
[    2.209449] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    2.209466] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    2.209508] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
[    2.209526] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    2.209567] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
[    2.209570] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    2.209610] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
[    2.209613] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    2.209676] ACPI: Fan [FAN0] (off)
[    2.209707] ACPI: Fan [FAN1] (off)
[    2.220946] ACPI: Invalid active2 threshold
[    2.225811] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    2.225817] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (51 C)
[    2.235815] thermal LNXTHERM:01: registered as thermal_zone1
[    2.235821] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (51 C)
[    2.235871] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    2.235879] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
[    2.235906] ERST: Table is not found!
[    2.235908] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    2.235952] isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...
[    2.235976] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    2.261813] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
[    2.589891] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[    2.605908] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    2.606002] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: Intel Sandybridge Chipset
[    2.606103] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 2097152K total, 262144K mappable
[    2.607580] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected 65536K stolen memory
[    2.607711] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 256M @ 0xd0000000
[    2.609266] brd: module loaded
[    2.610051] loop: module loaded
[    2.610176] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    2.610189] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    2.610245] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.625436] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x5 impl SATA mode
[    2.625446] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm led clo pio slum part ems apst 
[    2.625457] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.633980] scsi0 : ahci
[    2.634062] scsi1 : ahci
[    2.634131] scsi2 : ahci
[    2.634198] scsi3 : ahci
[    2.634267] scsi4 : ahci
[    2.634333] scsi5 : ahci
[    2.634435] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7c06000 port 0xf7c06100 irq 41
[    2.634438] ata2: DUMMY
[    2.634441] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7c06000 port 0xf7c06200 irq 41
[    2.634443] ata4: DUMMY
[    2.634444] ata5: DUMMY
[    2.634446] ata6: DUMMY
[    2.634810] Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    2.634830] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    2.634832] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    2.634882] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    2.634978] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    2.634993] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    2.635009] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.635013] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.635058] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.635084] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
[    2.638952] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.638968] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: irq 16, io mem 0xf7c08000
[    2.653401] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.653599] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.653603] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    2.653663] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
[    2.653679] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.653682] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.653725] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.653747] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    2.657622] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.657637] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xf7c07000
[    2.673395] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.673575] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.673578] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    2.673635] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    2.673647] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.673692] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    2.673743] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PSM1] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    2.677220] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    2.677226] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    2.677344] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.677670] rtc_cmos 00:08: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    2.677710] rtc0: alarms up to one year, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    2.677764] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    2.677833] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    2.677851] EISA: Probing bus 0 at eisa.0
[    2.677852] EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    2.677855] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    2.677856] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    2.677858] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    2.677860] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    2.677862] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    2.677864] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    2.677865] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    2.677867] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    2.677869] EISA: Detected 0 cards.
[    2.677877] cpufreq-nforce2: No nForce2 chipset.
[    2.678169] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    2.678638] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    2.678640] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    2.678827] TCP cubic registered
[    2.678941] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.679394] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.679398] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    2.679412] Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
[    2.679551] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
[    2.679690] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    2.679704] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.688439]   Magic number: 13:782:744
[    2.688564] rtc_cmos 00:08: setting system clock to 2013-09-17 17:44:21 UTC (1379439861)
[    2.691059] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    2.691061] EDD information not available.
[    2.953409] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    2.953452] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    2.955385] ata3.00: ATAPI: Optiarc DVD RW AD-7717H, 1.X0, max UDMA/100
[    2.957597] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.959726] ata1.00: ATA-8: SAMSUNG HM641JI, 2AJ10002, max UDMA/133
[    2.959730] ata1.00: 1250263728 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.965402] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    2.966087] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.966251] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SAMSUNG HM641JI  2AJ1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.966416] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1250263728 512-byte logical blocks: (640 GB/596 GiB)
[    2.966470] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.966475] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.966493] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.966500] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.967315] scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Optiarc  DVD RW AD-7717H  1.X0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.969511] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 16x/16x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.969515] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.969656] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.969798] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    3.027501]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    3.028201] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.028474] Freeing unused kernel memory: 744k freed
[    3.028720] Write protecting the kernel text: 5840k
[    3.028779] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 2388k
[    3.028781] NX-protecting the kernel data: 4400k
[    3.047033] udevd[125]: starting version 175
[    3.065860] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    3.065889] r8169 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    3.065940] r8169 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    3.066049] r8169 0000:03:00.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.066590] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xf842e000, e8:11:32:9d:e7:67, XID 0c900800 IRQ 42
[    3.066594] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    3.098171] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.098259] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    3.177311] Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 1995.467 MHz.
[    3.177325] Switching to clocksource tsc
[    3.209235] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    3.336649] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.341864] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.341946] hub 2-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    3.413306] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[   16.850061] Adding 4103164k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4103164k 
[   16.854512] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   16.899617] udevd[355]: starting version 175
[   16.937304] mei: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.937712] mei 0000:00:16.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   16.937722] mei 0000:00:16.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   16.937812] mei 0000:00:16.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   16.942855] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   16.944192] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   16.947101] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   16.952954] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   16.959037] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device WebCam SCB-1100N (2232:1008)
[   16.965329] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   16.966159] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   16.966164] Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   16.966253] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   16.966294] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   16.966341] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   16.966344] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: pci_resource_base = f8450000
[   16.966347] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x0
[   16.966538] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   16.966652] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 100 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   16.966780] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   16.966834] i915 0000:00:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   16.966864] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   16.987505] input: WebCam SCB-1100N as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input5
[   16.987617] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   16.987621] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   16.987986] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x166, CALIB=0x6
[   16.987991] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Device SKU: 0X50
[   16.987995] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0X1, Valid Rx ant: 0X3
[   16.988020] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 0 802.11a channels
[   17.004730] type=1400 audit(1379439875.812:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=399 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.005197] type=1400 audit(1379439875.816:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=399 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.005456] type=1400 audit(1379439875.816:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=399 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.022616] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   17.022623] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[   17.022626] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   17.024659] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[   17.083068] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   17.083071] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   17.083075] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   17.083077] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   17.083080] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   17.083082] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   17.083085] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   17.138997] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 32895
[   17.139130] Registered led device: phy0-led
[   17.139157] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[   17.141963] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   17.219123] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x450f00)
[   17.234753] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x08, 0x15, 0x0c.
[   17.310576] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
[   17.387049] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   17.596751] init: failsafe main process (799) killed by TERM signal
[   17.663112] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   17.663131] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   17.663134] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   17.663136] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   17.663138] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   17.663143] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.664970] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.664976] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.664979] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   17.702613] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.702618] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.724173] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   17.767015] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   17.780522] type=1400 audit(1379439876.588:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=884 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.781077] type=1400 audit(1379439876.592:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=884 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.787759] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   17.796641] type=1400 audit(1379439876.608:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=915 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.797352] type=1400 audit(1379439876.608:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=910 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.797931] type=1400 audit(1379439876.608:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=909 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.797963] type=1400 audit(1379439876.608:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=913 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.797976] type=1400 audit(1379439876.608:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=910 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.853483] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.853899] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.886155] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   17.886264] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[   17.886305] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   17.886307] drm: registered panic notifier
[   17.886518] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   17.937589] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link down
[   17.937756] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   17.938206] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   17.982258] acpi device:46: registered as cooling_device10
[   17.982474] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:44/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
[   17.982543] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: yes  post: no)
[   17.984072] acpi device:50: registered as cooling_device11
[   17.984266] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8
[   17.984318] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   17.984361] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   17.984411] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[   17.984494] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   17.984544] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   18.082992] init: alsa-restore main process (973) terminated with status 19
[   18.534018] HDMI status: Codec=3 Pin=5 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[   18.534100] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   18.534195] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[   18.534293] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   19.065605] init: anacron main process (1008) killed by TERM signal
[   19.141327] [drm:gen6_sanitize_pm] *ERROR* Power management discrepancy: GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS expected 16000000, was 12060000
[   19.380338] cfg80211: Found new beacon on frequency: 2467 MHz (Ch 12) on phy0
[   19.854517] bbswitch: version 0.7
[   19.854525] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   19.854532] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[   19.854624] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   19.854636] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[   19.854640] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[   19.854648] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   19.854651] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[   19.856807] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[   19.857055] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[   19.889866] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3
[   20.104606] wlan0: authenticate with 84:a8:e4:65:51:c4 (try 1)
[   20.107420] wlan0: authenticated
[   20.121233] wlan0: associate with 84:a8:e4:65:51:c4 (try 1)
[   20.126503] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 84:a8:e4:65:51:c4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   20.126511] wlan0: associated
[   20.133857] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   31.916932] [drm:gen6_sanitize_pm] *ERROR* Power management discrepancy: GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS expected 160d0000, was 16000000
[   60.834851] [drm:gen6_sanitize_pm] *ERROR* Power management discrepancy: GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS expected 000d0000, was 160d0000
[  126.255771] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[  126.365060] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  126.365067] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  126.371346] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input2
[  126.374198] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1024 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input12
[  126.374345] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1024] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2:1
[  126.376692] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2011 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input13
[  126.376879] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2011] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2:2
[  126.718779] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx aggregation enabled on ra = 84:a8:e4:65:51:c4 tid = 0
[ 1245.220487] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx aggregation enabled on ra = 84:a8:e4:65:51:c4 tid = 6
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: I want to past the output of dmesg but it's too big to use a comment. How should I do that?

Comment: Try pasting at `http://paste.ubuntu.com/`, and add the link in your question.